# Bootstrap 4 card usage with responsive next/image

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, next.js

```
 <div className="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div className="col-md-3 mt-3">
      <div className="card bg-light">
        <div className="card-img-top">
          <Image
            src="/character1.png"
            alt="Picture of the author"
            layout="fill"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">
          <h5 className="card-title">Emirhan Sirkeci</h5>
          <p className="text-muted">Developer</p>
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a href="https://github.com/justChargin" target="_blank">
              <Icon icon="akar-icons:github-fill" />
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/username/" target="_blank">
              <Icon icon="akar-icons:instagram-fill" />
            </a>
            <a href="mailto:emirhansirkeci8@gmail.com" target="_blank">
              <Icon icon="cib:gmail" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I replaced normal  html element with next/image component. But im facing with responsive issues. Check out the screenshot below.

[image]

As you can see, Image component is top of the card-body. How can i place my Image component like others? When i give Image component fixed width and height properties, its stop being responsive. I also tried giving it width height properties that include "100%" value

Answer (score 1):

next/image is rendered inside a span with absolute position. That's why it is overflowing the card-body.
You can fix it by adding some CSS to the `card-img-top` like the following example:

```
.card-img-top {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Or you can override some CSS properties for the rendered next/image HTML elements:

```
.card-img-top span,
.card-img-top span img {
  position: static !important;
}

.card-img-top span img {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-dzc7yr?file=styles/globals.css)